# APPJAR PYTHON how to create a table for preset data?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've tried creating a table using the .addTable() function but it doesn't seem to recognise this command, is this not the correct command as it says on the appjar website.

```
from appJar import gui

app = gui()
app.setFont(20)
app.addTable("g1",
             [["Name", "Age", "Gender"],
             ["Fred", 45, "Male"],
             ["Tina", 37, "Female"],
             ["Clive", 28, "Male"],
             ["Betty", 51, "Female"]])
app.go()
```

**the error I get is shown below:**

Warning - Unknown function:addTable ('g1', [['Name', 'Age', 'Gender'], ['Fred', 45, 'Male'], ['Tina', 37, 'Female'], ['Clive', 28, 'Male'], ['Betty', 51, 'Female']]) {}

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are running Python 2 but only installed appJar for Python 3.

Try installing appJar for Python 2.
`pip2 install appJar`

Or try running it in Python 3.
`python3 filename.py`

Also, try running `python --version` and `pip --version`. That may clear up some confusion for you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be your version of appJar - in earlier versions, the `table` was called `grid` - so you could try calling `.addGrid()` instead, or try updating appJar:

```
sudo pip install appJar --upgrade
```

Or, download the newest zip file.